# В динамическом массиве нужно перегрузить ++(добавление элемента в конец), В чём проблема?

Tags: c++

```
#ifndef DYNAMICARRAY_H
#define DYNAMICARRAY_H

#include <iostream>
using std::ostream;

class DynamicArray
{
    friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &output, const DynamicArray &array);
public:
    DynamicArray() = default;
    DynamicArray(int n);
    DynamicArray(int *arr, int n);
    ~DynamicArray();

    DynamicArray &operator++(const int n);

    int &operator[](int n);

    void showSize() const;
private:
    int size=NULL;
    int *ptr;
};

#endif

//DynamicArray.cpp
#include "DynamicArray.h"

#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::cin;

ostream & operator<<(ostream & output, const DynamicArray & arr)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.size; i++)
        output << arr.ptr[i] << ' ';

    return output;
}

DynamicArray::DynamicArray(int n) :size(n)
{
    ptr = new int[size];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        ptr[i] = 0;
}

DynamicArray::DynamicArray(int * arr, int n) :size(n)
{
    ptr = new int[size];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        ptr[i] = arr[i];
}

DynamicArray::~DynamicArray()
{
    delete[] ptr;
}

DynamicArray &DynamicArray::operator++(const int n)
{
    DynamicArray temp(size);

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        temp[i] = ptr[i];

    int newSize = size;

    delete[] ptr;
    ptr = new int[size++];

    for (int i = 0; i < newSize; i++) 
        ptr[i] = temp[i];

    ptr[size-1] = n;

    return *this;
}

int &DynamicArray::operator[](int n)
{
    if (n < 0 || n >= size)
        exit(1);

    return ptr[n];
}

void DynamicArray::showSize() const
{
    cout << size << endl;
}

//Source.cpp
#include "DynamicArray.h"

#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::cin;

int main()
{
    setlocale(NULL, "RUS");
    int arr[10] = { 10,5,9,7,-5,0,7,-9,100,5 }; 

    DynamicArray a(arr,10);

    cout << a << endl;
    cout << "количество элементов: ";
    a.showSize();
    a.operator++(0);
    cout << a << endl;
    cout << "количество элементов: ";
    a.showSize();

    return 0;
}
```

При запуске появляется ошибка, но результат правильный
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И последнее. Объясните за что отвечает амперсанд в `DynamicArray &operator++(const int n);`

Comment: Не очень вообще говоря понятно зачем добавление элемента в дин массив обозначать оператором инфкс инкремента (можно просто по старинке юзать push_back(const int value) и возвращение по ссылке используется для того чтобы не создавать объект заново (как и при передачи по ссылке). Я бы ещё подумал над обработкой исключений как например при выходе за пределы массива использовать throw out_of_range(); И тут я может уже утрирую, но можно также для доп безопасности разделить некоторые части программы на safe и unsafe зоны (которые могут бросать исключения)

Answer (score 1):

Мда. Ваш код называется - "мы не ищем в жизни легких путей"...

Ну да ладно. Как минимум ошибка тут:

```
ptr = new int[size++];

...

ptr[size-1] = n;
```

Итак, вы выделяете `size` элементов, потом увеличиваете это `size` на 1. Пусть, скажем, было `size = 5`. Вы выделили массив из 5 элементов, `size` после этого стало равно 6. Вы обращаетесь к элементу `ptr[5]`, которого **не существует** - память для него не выделена...

Дальше не смотрел.

Comment: Да там ошибка, я так написал потому что, если написать `ptr[size] = n;` на 11-ом месте мусор, а  если `ptr[size-1] = n;` вроде результат правильный но с ошибкой

Comment: Не пытайтесь методом проб и ошибок программировать - ни к чему хорошему это не приведет. Лучше думайте, считайте, рисуйте на бумажке схему размещения в памяти и куда вы обращаетесь. Вы и сейчас, похоже, не хотите понять, что я пишу, а просто каким-то исправлением добиться, чтоб не падало :( А правильное это исправление или нет - уже неважно...

Comment: Как закрыть тему?